# Locking script when accessing spreadsheet doesnot work

Tags: concurrency, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api

My problem is how to ensure that no data will be lost while concurrent access.

I have script published as web-app. I want to add new row to DATA_SHEET. The function that handles submit button looks like this:

```
function onButtonSubmit(e) {
  var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
  var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
  while (! lock.tryLock(1000))
    ;
  var ssheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_ID);
  var sheet = ssheet.getSheetByName(DATA_SHEET);
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn();
  var rangeToInsert = sheet.getRange(lastRow+1, 1, 1, lastCol);
  var statText = rangeToInsert.getA1Notation();
  rangeToInsert.setValues(<some data from webapp form>);
  app.getElementById('statusLabel').setText(statText);
  lock.releaseLock();
  return app;
}
```

But it seems that this does not work. When I open two forms and click submit button within one second, it shows same range in statsLabel and writes data into same range. So I lose data from one form.

What is wrong with this code? It seems like tryLock() does not block script.

Is there any other way how to prevent concurrent write access to sheet?

Comment: It seems that locking in web apps is an [apps script issue](http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1776)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be worth taking a look at [`appendRow()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendRow(Object)), rather than using `getLastRow()`/`setValues()` etc.

> Allows for atomic appending of a row to a spreadsheet; can be used
>   safely even when multiple instances of the script are running at the
>   same time. Previously, one would have to call getLastRow(), then write
>   to that row. But if two invocations of the script were running at the
>   same time, they might both read the same value for getLastRow(), and
>   then overwrite each other's values.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it tomorow. It's better solution than lock.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (! lock.tryLock(1000))
    ;
```

seems a bit hinky.  Try this instead:

```
  if (lock.tryLock(30000))  {
    // I got the lock!  Wo000t!!!11 Do whatever I was going to do!
  } else {
    // I couldn’t get the lock, now for plan B :(
    GmailApp.sendEmail(“admin@example.com”, “epic fail”,
        “lock acquisition fail!”);
  }
```

http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/10/concurrency-and-google-apps-script.html

Comment: I want to wait until lock is released by another instance.

Comment: What if it's never released?  What if the first user walks away from his computer?  Your strategy should be to lock only when you need to write, and writing shouldn't take that long, really.  If your contention is more than two users, you need a better solution such as a database.

Comment: Yes some DB is better solution but I have to do this in google spreadsheet. Anyway I can break while cycle after n iterations and then finish with error message. I'm using lock only in submit button handler when trying to write new row.

Comment: I tried your solution and it does not work. Two submited forms at almost same time writes data to same row.

Answer (score 0):

You must insert this code when using getLastRow()/setValues() with lock.

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
// before
lock.releaseLock();
```